# Angular2 folder path

Tags: typescript, angular

My file is located in: `dev/Posts/spinner.component.ts`
I want to move it to `dev/CustomHtml/spinner.component.ts`

So instead of :
      `import {SpinnerComponent} from './spinner.component';`
Should be:
    `import {SpinnerComponent} from 'dev/CustomHtml/spinner.component';`

, but it doesn't work.

I can't seem to find any good documentation about this.
Please point me to some documentation, or give some examples here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `../` to go parent route, use this instead:
`../CustomHtml/spinner.component`

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure i've tried that before and didn't work, but now it does.